# Template for specific method

Tags: c++, templates, friend

I'm creating a class for matrix.
It's a homework with templates, so i created 2 methods for multiplication, one where the matrix are equal the other is when i have just [x][y] [y][z].
Then i created the first one

```
#define TEMPLATEMATRIX template<class T, int C, int R>
TEMPLATEMATRIX Matrix<T, C, R> operator* (Matrix<T, C, R> a, Matrix<T, C, R> b);
TEMPLATEMATRIX class Matrix{
....
friend Matrix<T, C, R> operator* <>(Matrix<T, C, R> a, Matrix<T, C, R> b);
...
};
```

And it works like a charm,

But when i tried to implement the second one i had some problems, i solved it with:

```
#define TEMPLATEMATRIXT template<class T, int C, int R, int R1>
TEMPLATEMATRIXT Matrix<T, R1, R> operator* (Matrix<T, R1, C> a, Matrix<T, C, R> b);

TEMPLATEMATRIX class Matrix{
....
template<int R1> friend Matrix<T, R1, R> operator* (Matrix<T, R1, C> a, Matrix<T, C, R> b);
...
};

//Multiplication
TEMPLATEMATRIXT Matrix<T, R1, R> operator* (Matrix<T, R1, C> a, Matrix<T, C, R> b){
  Matrix<T, R1, R> t;
  ...
  return t;
}
```

It compiles, but when i do.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Matrix<int, 100, 19> operator*<100>(Matrix<int, 100, 123>, Matrix<int, 123, 19>)", referenced from:
      _main in cciAzuMs.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

like the method was not implemented.

How i do in the main()

```
  Matrix<int, 123, 19> ta2;

  Matrix<int, 100, 123> ta;
  Matrix<int, 100, 19> rr=ta*ta2;
```

i don't know if i implemented this template right.

Thanks

Comment: You said two different matrices look like `[x][y]` and `[z][y]`, but the signature of operator* looks like as if they were `[x][y]` and `[y][z]`.

Comment: Sorry, its [x][y] [y][z]. i'll edit

Comment: It seems that the friend is being ignored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

The problem was the

```
#define TEMPLATEMATRIX template<class T, int C, int R>
#define TEMPLATEMATRIXT template<class T, int C, int R, int R1>
```

I cannot use 2 templates (not in my case) with the same "vars"

```
#define TEMPLATEMATRIX template<class T, int C, int R>
#define TEMPLATEMATRIXT template<class T2, int C2, int R2, int R1>
```

It solved my problem